# When using modulus operator, I want the number not remainder 0

Tags: python, modulo

First of all, I have to say that my English is so poor.
I could not find any better title for this article.
Anyway, I want to ask you guys, about Python.

Please look at the code below.

```
for i in range(1,11):
    print(i,'-->',i%4)
```

Results in

```
1 --> 1
2 --> 2
3 --> 3
4 --> 0
5 --> 1
6 --> 2
7 --> 3
8 --> 0
9 --> 1
10 --> 2
```

All the results are ok, except those 4's multiples. I want 4 is 4, 8 is 4, 12 is 4... not 0(Zero).
Something like this.

```
1 --> 1
2 --> 2
3 --> 3
4 --> 4
5 --> 1
6 --> 2
7 --> 3
8 --> 4
9 --> 1
10 --> 2
```

Any Clue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

```
for i in range(1,11):
    print(i,'-->',(i-1)%4+1)
```

Comment: We all blank occasionally!

Answer (score 4):

I personally find the most intuitive (keeps the intent of the modulus easier to read):

```
for i in range(1,11):
    print(i,'-->',i%4 or 4)
```

Comment: @DonRoby Saves a bit of arithmetic anyway - just relies on someone understanding how booleans work in Python - but yours can be applied to more languages ;)

Comment: @Jon Clements Thank you very much. Yes, I agree with Don Roby. It is pythonic.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this simple construction:

```
if i % 4 == 0:
    i = 4
```

May be i dont understand your question.

Comment: You are right. But I want some code not using if. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
for i in range(1,11):
    if i%4 == 0:
        print(i,'-->',4)
    else:
        print(i,'-->',i%4)
```

or

```
for i in range(1,11):
    print(i,'-->',4 if i%4 == 0 else i%4)
```

Comment: Thanks. But I want shorter ones.